# SHA-256 on the database side

Tags: database, security, hash, password-protection, sha256

I'm making a mobile app for tv series. Basically like a tracker, to know what episodes to watch and when. And I wanted to store the information like episodes watched, user shows on a database. (the info about shows I get from a rest api)

So the thing is I don't find the need to have a server here, I just don't know what it should do.

And the problem is I'd like to make the database secure. And from what I've read the best practice is to create a salt using a cryptographically strong random number generator and prepend it to the password and then hash the whole thing using a hash algorithm, for example the SHA-256.
Then I store a hashed password and the salt in the database, and when I want to check if the password is correct, just hash it again and compare to the one in database.

So I have a special class in Java that can create such a salt, and all I needed to know is where and how to hash the whole thing. And what is what I'm asking about. I would not like to create a server that would just hash passwords.

Also another thing is how to go about implementing auto-login, which I also wanted to add once I figured this out.

I hope it's clearer now what I want to accomplish here.

Comment: That's a matter of opinion, but you shouldn't use SHA256 at all - it's considered weak. Use SHA512 instead, or if you are using PHP use `password_hash ()`

Comment: Neither. Server-side, before sending it to the database. Do it in your app itself, not in the database. Use an established library like `bcrypt` and *do not under any circumstances* roll your own salting and hashing scheme.

Comment: What does it mean to roll my own scheme? Also there is no server side since I'm talking about a mobile app here that uses a database to store some data. Should I hash it on the phone before sending it to the database?

Comment: I mean, do not do your own salting and hashing, like trying to generate a random salt and then do SHA-whatever. Use a library. And there definitely should be *some* server side other than the database. If your mobile app connects directly to the database, with no intermediary layer, that implies that you are storing database credentials in the client. That is a ***huge*** security hole, so I hope that's not what you're doing. (By the way, how are we even supposed to know this is a mobile app, given that you didn't mention that anywhere in your question?)

Comment: Also, to clarify, if you are *not* salting and are just hashing, you already have made a huge error. This is one of many reasons not to reinvent the wheel on password storage.

Comment: Database credentials ? I actually wanted to generate salts using java SecureRandom class. And then either hash it on the database side or the app side. And I wouldn't store any of that on the device, just get the hash and salt from the database, compare the hashes and so on.

Comment: @HoboSapiens: [SHA-256](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-256) is *not* considered weak. You may be thinking of SHA-1 instead.

Comment: @Greyshack That isn't really making sense. You need to ask this question again and explain exactly what it is you want to do. Again, though, making the client in any way responsible for password hashing and comparisons is insecure. It would be easy if not trivial for a sophisticated user of your software to engineer an attack and log in with elevated credentials.

Comment: I'm sorry, I've edited my question to make it clearer. Can you try answering again? :)

Comment: @ilmarikaronen you're quite right - is too early in the morning!

Comment: @Greyshack I think there are fundamental misunderstandings here. As I understand it, you want this: (1) a database server and (2) a mobile client written in Java. The client would connect to the server, retrieve a hash, and compare it to something. If that's what you mean, then it is horribly insecure because you have to distribute the database credentials. It would be very easy for the end user to extract them and take total control of the database. If, instead, you're talking about connecting to a local-only database on the device, how do you plan to connect before verifying the credentials?

Comment: P.S. Please tag me by typing `@EdCottrell` in your comments. Otherwise, I won't know you've replied to me.

Comment: @EdCottrell Okay, I wanted to do it the first way you described. How should I do it then ? What is the optimal solution?

Comment: You're going to have to have a server-side system to handle authentication of your users. The server-side app will have the credentials for the database; the clients will not. This is going to be a big undertaking, and explaining it is too much for a single question on here. I'd suggest you do some reading about authorization and authentication on [security.stackexchange.com](http://security.stackexchange.com) and OWASP (search Google).

Comment: @EdCottrell Thanks. So basically write a server that will do the connecting do the database part for the clients? Therefore I'm guessing it's just better to store all the data I need on the device itself - the shows that the user is watching ,the episodes he's already watched.

Comment: Yes, the server needs to handle the database connection, as well as user permissions/roles and account management, if any. It's fine to store user data only on the device, *if* you don't need it anywhere else.

Comment: @EdCottrell Just seems like way too much work for what I'm trying to accomplish here. But still a good exercise I guess. I'll look into it.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're building a mobile app that stands alone, ie doesn't talk to a server.

You want the app to be password protected (even if their phone already is), and you want to store this password hashed, so that the pwd cannot be recovered on say a lost then rooted phone.

SHA256 is a fine hash but what you want is a *real slow* hash. Use bcrypt, PBKDF2, or scrypt.

The salt is not a secret.

When the user creates their account, create the salt, hash the pwd with the salt and store the password and salt somewhere. Each time the user logs in, get the salt, hash the password the same as before, and compare to saved password. If same, user authenticates.

You don't need to store the pwd in sqlite. It's probably easier just to store it in a text file.